# SP 2010 Views on a list depending on the access rights

Tags: 2010, development

Is there a possibility to link views on a custom list to the access rights on this list?

 E.g. I have a custom list with information stored in diffrent columns
I've created two views: one for owners of the site and one for visitors

- The owners view displays all columns

- The visitors only have read rights on the list and can only see a specific number of columns

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we can achieve this using **SINGLE** WebPart using OOB options.

Using **Target Audience Feature**, use two webparts in pointing to the Admin View and Vistors View respectively , then configure the Target Audience feature to Hide/Show based on the group.

I assume the owners of the list is in diff group as I think OOB Owner group can still both the webparts.

**UPDATE :****

**Custom**

- Create two views ( one for Owners and other for Visitors)
- Check the logged-in user groups to see where part of Owners / Visitors, and get the respective CAML of the view dynamically ( using SPView)
- Option 1 : use a DataView webpart and assign the CAML query on runtime
- Option 2 : Query the List and use a SPGridView and bind the results

I would strongly suggest you to use the OOB way.

Comment: It doesn't need to be an OOTB solution

Comment: Check the update in the answer

Comment: I am also new in sharepoint. I am uses sharepoint 2010 and i also have the same issue. but i don't know how to use these both the method Option 1 : use a DataView webpart and assign the CAML query on runtime
Option 2 : Query the List and use a SPGridView and bind the results Can you give me a blog/ video link to help me or guide me the steps to achieve the same ? like
-- how to add Dataview webpart using sharepoint designer 2010 also how to apply CAML query runtime ?
-- if we use SPGridView then how would we use that query and bind result can you guide me further ? Looking for your answer plea

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of third party solutions which provide security for views.

One such solution I have configured in the past is sharepoint boost, the permissions boost package.

This solution allows business users to configure view permissions as they require them.  It is easy to import and export the permissions as well.

This solution also allows column specific permissions, so columns will only be visible with the required permissions.